# Velocity of electrons ejected from Cl atom

Tags: electrons

When neutral $\ce{Cl}$ atoms are bombarded by high energy photons, causing ejection of electrons, which subshells' ejected electrons will have highest velocity?

I chose $1s$ because I thought more energy is needed to ejected those electrons so they might have higher velocity. My second choice $3s$ is right, but I can't explain why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be the $3s$ shell because less energy is required to bump it off course. Due to electron repulsion and the shielding effect, the $e-$ in the $3s$ is more prone to get dislodged. And of course because of this, it will have a higher velocity when it gets **bumped** off. **Another concept to note: $e-$ will have more energy at higher energy levels.**

A reason why it wouldn't be the $1s$ shell is because due to the strong pull on the $1s$ electron. Since it is on the first energy level, it is strongly **held** by the nucleus. ***Even it were to get dislodged it would move very slow because of the strong pull by the nucleus.***

Comment: so it's because 3s electrons after bumped off will have more kinetic energy leftover right?

Comment: Exactly. You figured it out.

Comment: Why not $3p$?  Aren't they further out and higher energy than $3s$ electrons?