# Which of the following releases the smallest amount of energy upon gaining an electron?

Tags: reactivity

$\ce{C}$, $\ce{Rb}$, $\ce{Ga}$, $\ce{Ge}$

I am confused in the sense that I don't know what it means by "released the smallest about of energy upon gaining?" would it be $\ce{Rb}$ because the shell is so big that when it loses an electron the overall energy doesn't really matter?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, this is similar to a question that I have answered before but I will just give you the reasoning for this phenomenon. I will **not** give you the answer since this appears to be a homework question.

**Why an atom gains energy when you take off an electron?**
Well for this, think of the attractions between the nucleus and the electrons, so when you must ***strip*** away an electron from this stability, you must add energy to do so.

**Why an atom releases energy when you add an electron?**
This one might be a little hard to grasp, but at the end it is not too bad. Essentially the molecule is becoming more stable. It is getting near to having a full octet. (Ignoring noble gasses). In other words the kinetic energy added by gaining the electron is released when the atom is achieving a stable state.

This is the general reasoning behind this, not too complicated, but I hope you will be able to understand it. Just, if you can't, remember the first one and think of the opposite for the second one.

---

Now, take a look at [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/30805/velocity-of-electrons-ejected-from-cl-atom/30813#30813) question, to help you with your question even more. You will then be able to deduce the correct answer.

Comment: Just to add clarity: It’s *not* only noble gases that gain energy if an electron is added. (You knew that and it’s not relevant to the asker’s specific question but before any confusion of any kind arises anywhere ;).)

Comment: Ok, alright. :)